# Clicking on a side of the text on the asp menu item; menu disappears

Tags: asp.net, menu, menuitem-selection

If user clicks on a side of the text in the drop down menu, the menu disappears but system performs no action and user needs to click right on the text. 
Clicking on a side should not disappear the menu but should stay there so that user should know that he has not clicked on the right place.

  **OR** 
Clicking on a side of the text should perform an action like in IE menu...

[http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/6074/menuldl.jpg http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/6074/menuldl.jpg](http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/6074/menuldl.jpg)

Does anyone have idea how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got solution.... Actually asp menu control rendered as anchor, we can set the display style of anchor as block....

```
 <style>
    #dvmnu a
    {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

where dvmnu is the div under which asp menu control exist.

Comment: This could be achieved with just CSS, yea?